# Excel ComboBox/Control text does not show/recognize special characters when active, but does when inactive

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into a weird issue.

I have assigned a string value to the list of a combobox that includes a unicode character.  In my case, these are triangles up/down (`ChrW(&H25B2)` = ▲ & `ChrW(&H25BC)` = ▼) to denote the ASC/DESC of the desired data sort.

Now, the problem is that Excel successfully displays the unicode character in the combobox only when the control is active (when I select or click on it).  BUT, when I click away from the control or change focus it displays a question mark (?), as if I am trying to display an unknown character.  The character always displays properly inside of a cell, but not a combobox.  I was thinking that maybe two different fonts are being displayed depending on active status, but this has not been set, and I see no option for this in the properties.  I also tried the decimal method for adding the characters (`ChrW(9660)` & `ChrW(9650)`), just in case, but that didn't change anything

What is going on here?  How can I have ▲ & ▼ always display properly.

EDIT: Having learned that VBA controls are limited to ANSI characters, and can't display Unicode characters, Is there a way to display the triangles like I want despite ANSI not having triangles or up/down arrows in its character set?

See code and image below to see what I mean.

[image]

```
Sub PopulateSortList()
    'Populate Sort Dropdown control
    With Sheet1.ComboBox_Sort
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Time - IN " & ChrW(&H25B2) 'Ascending
        .AddItem "Time - IN " & ChrW(&H25BC) 'Decending
        .AddItem "Time - OUT " & ChrW(&H25B2) 'Ascending
        .AddItem "Time - OUT " & ChrW(&H25BC) 'Decending
        .Font.Size = 11
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
        .SelectionMargin = False
        .ListIndex = 1    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion: `Private SortAscending As String`; `SortAscending = ChrW(&H25B2)` - then `.AddItem "Time - IN " & SortAscending`. That way you don't have to invoke the `ChrW` function & work out the character every single time you need it.

Comment: Question mark means "I don't know what that is" - VBA works off ANSI, not unicode. Find an ANSI character equivalent.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So I guess my question becomes: Is there a way to display the triangles like I want despite ANSI not having triangles or up/down arrows in it's recordset?

Comment: Try `Chr$(24)` and `Chr$(25)`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That displays a rectangle whether active or not.

Comment: Can you confirm what type of control this is? `Excel.ComboBox` ("form control"), or `MSForms.ComboBox` ("ActiveX control")? That said a work-around could be to simply append `(desc)` or `(asc)`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ActiveX control within a worksheet.  I was thinking of just appening with text, but I'd like to maintain some style...if possible.